Intuitive way to think about modular forms
For about a week I have been trying to learn about modular forms, but I always just get lost really quickly when I try to learn, and it all seems really convoluted. I have tried to use YouTube, countless websites, I think I have all the prerequisites down, but I just can’t seem to wrap my head around this. Is there a better or more intuitive way to think about modular forms?

This is a very broad question that is not appropriate for this website. Also if you want intuition, a modular form is basically something that changes in predictable ways when you change it, some patterns remain the same even if you modify it. Intuition is not really a mathematical concept though math is all about rigid logic and facts and proof, it's not really about subjective things like intuition, math is quite the opposite usually. You don't want to understand math with thoughts. You want to understand through previous math that you learned, if that makes sense. Math builds upon itself.

I think it is better to study in the way they appeared chronologically. It would be nice to have background in elliptic integrals, theta functions, elliptic functions and then the subject of modular forms will appear more natural.

That helps, thanks
